# I'm in a bind with pulling certain lines from a JSON file and adding them to CSV file

Tags: powershell, sentinel

I am in need of any help that can be given
I have about 300 JSON files that I'm looking to export the following values from JSON into an Excel Spreadsheet or a CSV file.

````
```
displayName = Base Use Case
enabled = True/False
Description=Description
```
````

As my starting point, I tried to just get the displayName to export to a csv file and I have not been able to get it working using the scripting below.

````
```
$Directory = 'C:\Temp\My_Rules'
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force -Include *.json | #where fullname - notmatch 
'Marketing' | where fullname -notmatch 'Geral' | 
ForEach {

$Folder = $Shell.Namespace($_.DirectoryName)
$File = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force -Include *.json # 
$Folder.ParseName($_.Name)
$Duration = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File, 27)

   [PSCustomObject]@{
    Directory = $_.Directory -Replace ([Regex]::Escape("\Videos")), "" -Replace 
([Regex]::Escape($Directory)), ""
    Name = $_.Name -Replace ".scheduledanalyticrules.rule", ""
    Size = "$([int]($_.length / 1kb)) KB"
    # Duration = $Duration

}
} | Export-Csv -Path ".\usecasedepoy.csv" -NoTypeInformation # -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";"
    
```
````

Comment: Use: [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) to parse your Json properties.

Comment: I tried that earlier without luck,

Comment: I couldn't edit my comment, but I've tried adding the Convert after the Get-Child and both before and after Export-Csv without luck

Comment: You need to reveal more of your `json` tree structure to be able to help you with the ` ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet or check for related [`PowerShell ConvertFrom-Json` Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=PowerShell%20ConvertFrom-Json)

Comment: What I'm looking for doesn't show up as available attribute. I can't paste a screenshot but there are only 4 items that appear when I'm looking at something simple like the following

Comment: $MyJsonVar = Get-Content @(".\Scheduled_Analytical_Rules\(Preview)TImapDomainentitytoDnsEvents(ASIMDNSSchema).json") #| ConvertFrom-Json
$myJsonObject = $MyJsonVar | ConvertFrom-Json

$myJsonObject.parameters.workspace |ConvertTo-Json

The above will output data however, if I change 
$myJsonObject.displayName |ConvertTo-Json

the output is blank